# Error Installing PECL Package: Mysql_xdevapi

Tags: collections, mkdir, pecl, mysqlnd

I'm getting the following error when i run this command

```
sudo pecl install mysql_xdevapi
```

Error:

```
/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-nabilashahidhnTBCl/mysql_xdevapi-8.0.12/libtool: line 1280: xmysqlnd/proto_gen/mysqlx_connection.loT: No such file or directory
mkdir xmysqlnd/proto_gen/.libs
mkdir: xmysqlnd/proto_gen: No such file or directory
make: *** [xmysqlnd/proto_gen/mysqlx_connection.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: any chances with this? I am stuck at the same spot

Comment: couldn't figure out the solution

Comment: The X DevAPI is dependent on the Google Protobuf code for the new X DevAPI and the Boost.Geometry libraries.  Andrei's answer below correctly shows how to get the prerequisites installed.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL X DevAPI PECL Extension

You can find the MySQL X DevAPI among the many PECL extensions and you can get the latest tarball of source code and also a link to the homepage.  And on that home page are directions for installing/configure the extension. The docs say to do the followings and assume you already have MySQL 8.0.11 installed (or go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads for the MySQL apt repo software; Install it and then run  `sudo apt-get install mysql-shell mysql-server`).

```
$ apt install build-essential libprotobuf-dev libboost-dev openssl protobuf-compiler
$ add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$ apt install php7.2-cli php7.2-dev php7.2-mysql php7.2-pdo php7.2-xml
$ pecl install mysql_xdevapi
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have to change php version to php7.3 , php7.4 failed to install mysql_xdevapi from pecl

Comment: This sucks! I have all my production machines running with 7.4...