# Cannot install php mysql_xdevapi extension

Tags: php, pecl, mysql-x-devapi

I need to install some composer packages, but all of those require php mysql_xdevapi extension.
I'm trying to install following these [instructions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql-xdevapi.installation.php), but PECL gives me this error:

```
/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootkr7lTy/mysql_xdevapi-8.0.21/libtool: line 1283: xmysqlnd/proto_gen/mysqlx.loT: No such file or directory
mkdir xmysqlnd/proto_gen/.libs
mkdir: cannot create directory 'xmysqlnd/proto_gen/.libs': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:263: xmysqlnd/proto_gen/mysqlx.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

PHP version: 7.4.8, PEAR version: 1.10.9

Comment: Same problem here... no solution! :(
This guy https://stackoverflow.com/a/63025374/3681102 said that he was successful with PHP7.3, but I could not install it correctly with 7.3, nor 7.4 (did not try it with 7.2).
All my production machines are running with 7.4, I dont want to downgrade!